# TFS build drop folder does not contain database scripts

Tags: c#, tfs, build, msbuild

This is probably a novice MS build query.

I have created an empty C# project called Database with only database sql scripts. The reason for doing this is to have the scripts output into the TFS build drop folder, since adding scripts as solution items were not output without changing templates/tweaking the XAML files.

[image]

However I noticed that the new project does not have a main entry point and hence compilation fails. So i went to Build Configuration manager and disabled both 'Build' and 'Deploy' which means I do not get the compilation error.

But the problem is that I am unable to find the scripts output anywhere in the TFS build drop folders. Please advise.

Comment: Any particular reason of not adding the script to a project that actually builds and has output in the TFS build drop folder? You can simply change the file property in the VS (Copy to Output Directory) to "Copy Always".

Comment: Just want to keep it in a separate project in the solution.

Comment: Looked at 'Copy To Output Directory'. That is at a file level. It will be tedious since we have a lot of scripts, plus one needs to remember to do that for every new script that is added.

Comment: Why not create an actual SSDT project and compile it into a deployable DACPAC? Managing SQL scripts manually is not a great practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your compilation error:

1. Open the project properties.
2. Select the 'Application' area on the left (if it is not already selected)
3. Change the 'Output Type' from **Console Application** to **Class Library**

Once this is done you will be able to build and deploy without compilation errors even though you do not have a main() entry point.

This still will not resolve your concern about the 'Copy to Output Directory'.  Visual Studio by default recognizes .sql files as having a build action of Content with an Output property of 'Do Not Copy'.

Comment: yes that solved the compilation issue. As expected changing it to class library is creating a DLL although I have no use for it.